# Ha uma maneira útil para destacar um(a) elemento/tag HTML numa determinada cor

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-tags

Pois bem, desejo definir uma cor ao estilo tag.

O exemplo a seguir altera o estilo de um elemento

```
<p id="tag"> parágrafo </p>
```

Para alterar o estilo de um elemento HTML, usa-se esta sintaxe:

```
<script>
   document.getElementById("tag").style.color = "blue";
</script>
```

Até aqui tudo bem, mas queria eu poder definir uma cor direto na tag exibida na página

Então seria sintaxe abaixo, que coloca o elemento HTML visível sobre a página web.

```
&lt;p&gt; parágrafo &lt;/p&gt;
```

Resultado da sintaxe acima, sua saída esta como na linha abaixo

```
<p> parágrafo </p>
```

Portanto quero que `<p>` e `</p>` tenham cor definda, estipulado por mim, por exemplo - *azul*

Comment: http://highlight.js

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você pode usar os seletores [`before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/::before) e [`after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Web/CSS/:after):

```css
.paragraphClass::before, .paragraphClass::after{
  color: blue;
}
.paragraphClass::before{
  content: '<p>';
}
.paragraphClass::after{
  content: '</p>';
}
```

```html
<div class="paragraphClass">foo</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Segue uma outra alternativa.

```css
body {
    background-color: lightblue;
    font-size: 10pt;
}

#code {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
}


samp { color: tomato; }
```

```html
<strong>Exemplo: o Meu Primeiro código de mark-up</strong>

<pre id="code">

    <samp>&lt;html&gt;</samp> 

      <samp>&lt;head&gt;</samp>

        <samp>&lt;title&gt;</samp> Título <samp>&lt;/title&gt;</samp>

      <samp>&lt;/head&gt;</samp>

        <samp>&lt;body&gt;</samp>

          <samp>&lt;p&gt;</samp> parágrafo <samp>&lt;/p&gt;</samp>

        <samp>&lt;/body&gt;</samp>

    <samp>&lt;/html&gt;</samp>

</pre>
```

> Esta tag `samp` representa uma saída de um resultado computacional.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode definir uma regra CSS para a própria tag.

```
p {
  color: #F00;
}
```

Assim todos as tags `p` vão ficar com a cor vermelha.

Comment: Então Marcos a real função que necessito e cheguei a conclusão é pós-processamento é code mark-up, ou marcação de código. Como descrevi em minha pergunta, na verdade não seria o elemento interno do documento HTML, ou seja, não seria a tag propriamente em si, mas sim sobre a própria página como texto, sem interferência alguma no HTML. A duas resposta era exatamente o que procurava. :D